# I want to access by avoiding x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid error with goquery

Tags: go

```
doc, err := goquery.NewDocument(site_url)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
        return
    }
```

Running the above gives the error 
`panic: Get site_url: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid`

How do I bypass certificate verification and access any site?

After searching on Google, using `client.Get` and `http.Get`,
I found a way to do & `tls.Config {InsecureSkipVerify: true}` but I can't find a way with `goquery`

go version go1.13.5

centos7

Comment: Just stick to doing the request yourself and use [NewDocumentFromReader](https://godoc.org/github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery#NewDocumentFromReader), passing the response body.

Comment: I did it!
Thank you!